# AWS EC2 Container Service / Elastic Beanstalk Docker Container Port udp binding

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

According to the documentation of ECS task definitions, this is how we define port mappings.

```
"portMappings": [
    {
        "containerPort": integer,
        "hostPort": integer
    }
    ...
]
```

By default this is binding port over `tcp`. How to achieve `udp` port bindings to docker containers running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Multi-container) or with AWS ECS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP support has been missing still from the GA release of the [Amazon EC2 Container Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ecs/), see [Ports are assumed to be TCP (issue #2)](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/2) of the [Amazon ECS Container Agent](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent). Luckily this surprising gap has already been addressed and the new ECS agent version is *pending release* - I would expect this release to happen anytime soon and the [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) team is usually quick to update their official images in due course (keep an eye on the [Elastic Beanstalk forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=86) for resp. announcements).

Comment: I believe this still is not supported on Elastic Beanstalk. Can anyone confirm otherwise? Sad that it's taking them so long. Flies in contrast to the above assertion that they are "quick" 6 months is certainly not quick by my standards.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/2, this should be now supported:

```
"portMappings": [
    {
        "containerPort": integer,
        "hostPort": integer,
        "protocol": "udp",
    }
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

@jrc's answer is correct. I've tested it with Raintank's Graphite stack image, `raintank/graphite-stack`, on Elastic Beanstalk multi-container Docker environment (which on contrary to single-container Docker environment which uses *nginx* as a reverse proxy to the container's port and doesn't support multi-ports and UDP, is a frontend to ECS). Corresponding `Dockerrun.aws.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "stack",
      "image": "raintank/graphite-stack",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 850,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3000,
          "hostPort": 80
        },
        {
          "containerPort": 8125,
          "hostPort": 8125,
          "protocol": "udp"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then logging in to the corresponding EC2 instance and typing `sudo docker ps` gives:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                       NAMES
12a5711dab47        raintank/graphite-stack          "/usr/bin/supervisord"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        443/tcp, 2003/tcp, 8125/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8125->8125/udp, 0.0.0.0:80->3000/tcp   ecs-awseb-test-abc-1-stack-abc
930a9b814df4        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest   "/agent"                 3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                                                                                    ecs-agent
```

Issuing *statsd* UDP packet manually, `echo "test.statsd:1|c" | nc -w 1 -u test.aws-region.elasticbeanstalk.com 8125`, I see it appearing in the Graphite.